# Azure Event Hubs with AsyncAPI

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, asyncapi, eventhub, data-mesh

As far as I understand, for streaming data mesh, people are using `AsyncAPI 2` to define their streaming data products in a `Kafka` based implementation.
Is it possible to use `AsyncAPI 2` for `Azure Event Hubs` to implement `Streaming Data Mesh`?

Comment: It should be possible to use AsyncAPI 2 for Azure Event Hubs in the context of implementing a Streaming Data Mesh. Do you seen any potential challenges in using it? AsyncAPI is a specification that’s designed to provide a universal way to describe asynchronous APIs, which includes not just streaming platforms like Apache Kafka, but also other message-driven platforms such as MQTT brokers, WebSockets, and indeed Azure Event Hubs.

Comment: I was curious about Azure way to define schema/metadata to be able to form lineage for DPs.